# Directional derivative with function composition

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$,  $g: \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^d$ with $g(x, 0) = x$ and suppose that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ both $v(x) := \partial_{t}g(x, t)|_{t=0}$ and the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v(x)$ exist.

Consider the derivative of $f(g(x, t))$ wrt. $t$ evaluated at $0$. I was hoping to show that this equals the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v(x)$.

By assumption, there exists $\epsilon(x, t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ such that $g(x, t) = x + t v(x) + \epsilon(x, t) t$. Using this, I can write
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(g(x, h)) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h\{v(x)+\epsilon(x, h)\}) - f(x+hv(x))}{h} + \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+hv(x)) - f(x)}{h}.
$$
The second term is exactly the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v(x)$. I was hoping to give some nice condition under which the first term goes to 0 but perhaps it is already true? It is certainly true if I assume that $f$ is differentiable but I would like to assume less (e.g. just differentiability in some directions).

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(g(x, h)) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+hv(x)) - f(x)}{h}  $
$\iff$

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h\{v(x)+\epsilon(x, h)\}) - f(x+hv(x))}{h} = 0$  $\iff$

$\lim_{h \to 0} \lvert\frac{f(x+h\{v(x)+\epsilon(x, h)\}) - f(x+hv(x))}{h}\rvert = 0$

---

Instead of differentiability, we can for example assume $f$ to be Hölder Continuous and add some assumption to $\epsilon$.

$\mathbf{Definition}$ : $f:I\subset \Bbb R^n \rightarrow  \Bbb R $  is said to be Hölder continuous in $I$ if $\exists\alpha\gt0$ and $K\gt0$ such that $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert \leq K \|x-y\|^\alpha , \forall x,y \in I$

$\mathbf{Proposition}$ :
$f$ is $\alpha$-Hölder Continuous in some neighborhood of $x$ and $\lVert\epsilon(x,h)\rVert^{\alpha}=o(h^{\lvert\alpha-1\rvert})$ $\implies$
$\lim_{h \to 0} \lvert\frac{f(x+h\{v(x)+\epsilon(x, h)\}) - f(x+hv(x))}{h}\rvert = 0$

$\mathbf{Proof}$ :$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \lvert\frac{f(x+h\{v(x)+\epsilon(x, h)\}) - f(x+hv(x))}{h}\rvert 
= 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lvert f(x+h\{v(x)+\epsilon(x, h)\}) - f(x+hv(x))\rvert}{\lvert h \rvert} 
\le 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{K\ \lVert x+hv(x)- h\epsilon(x, h)) - x-hv(x)\rVert^{\alpha}}{\lvert h \rvert} 
= 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{K\ \lVert h\epsilon(x, h)\rVert^{\alpha}}{\lvert h \rvert} 
=
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{K\ \lvert h \rvert^{\alpha} \lVert \epsilon(x, h)\rVert^{\alpha}}{\lvert h \rvert} 
=
\lim_{h \to 0} {K\ \lvert h \rvert^{\alpha-1} \lVert \epsilon(x, h)\rVert^{\alpha}} = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

From this the thesis should follow.

---

Another route we can follow is this. We want
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h\{v(x)+\epsilon(x, h)\}) - f(x+hv(x))}{h} = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
to hold.
Now, if we assume for $f$ to be continuous in a neighbohrood of $x$ we can evaluate the limit, and this gives us:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h\{v(x)+\epsilon(x, h)\}) - f(x+hv(x))}{h} = 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{0}{0}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Here we can introduce a set of sufficient assumptions (maybe too strong for what you want) such that the indeterminate form is resolved and the limit goes to $0$.

$\mathbf{Definition}$ : let $\gamma_{v(x)+u(x)}(h)$ $\stackrel{\text{def}}= f(x+h\{v(x)+u(x)\})$ and $\gamma_v(x)(h)$ $\stackrel{\text{def}}= f(x+hv(x))$ and suppose that there exists two neighborhood $U$,$V$ in $\mathbb{R}$ centered at $0$ such that $\gamma_{v(x)+u(x)}(h)$ and $\gamma_{v(x)}(h)$ are respectively $C^1(U)$ and $C^1(V)$.

This should be equivalent to saying that $f$ is continuous in some neighborhood of $x$ along $v(x)$ and $u(x)+v(x)$.
Here we can introduce a (pretty strong in my opinion) assumption on $\epsilon$, namely for it to be dependent only on $x$: $\epsilon(x,h)=u(x)$. (Maybe we can be less restrictive on $\epsilon$, like assuming just continuity in $h$ but for the moment I'll settle for this condition).
We can then rewrite the previous limit:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\gamma_{v(x)+u(x)}(h) - \gamma_{v(x)}(h)}{h} 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Now we prove a result useful for later.

$\mathbf{Proposition}$ : let $\gamma_{w(x)}(h)$ be a function as defined above, then $\gamma_{w(x)}^{'}(0)=D_{w(x)}f(x)$

$\mathbf{Proof}$ :  by definition
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\gamma_w(x)^{'}(0)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h\{w(x)\}) - f(x)}{h}\stackrel{\text{def}}=D_{w(x)}f(x) 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
where the last term is the directional derivarive of $f$ at $x$ along $w(x)$.

Lets now add one last assumption, namely that $D_{v(x)+u(x)}f(x) = D_{v(x)}f(x)$ and we finally arrive at the following

$\mathbf{Proposition}$ :
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\gamma_{v(x)+u(x)}(h) - \gamma_{v(x)}(h)}{h}=0$

$\mathbf{Proof}$ :

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\gamma_{v(x)+u(x)}(h) - \gamma_{v(x)}(h)}{h} = \frac{0}{0}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
The situation admits the use of L'Hopital rule.

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\gamma_{v(x)+u(x)}(h) - \gamma_{v(x)}(h)}{h} =
\lim_{h \to 0} ({\gamma_{v(x)+u(x)}^{'}(h) - \gamma_{v(x)}^{'}(h)}) = 
D_{v(x)+u(x)}f(x) - D_{v(x)}f(x) = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

---

Just a note: from my very limited and defintely not sophisticated perspective (and from the limited time I've spent thinking about this), if you do not impose some additional conditions on $\epsilon$ then differentiability may well be the only way to go.